# Como criar um JSON usando o jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como eu faço para criar um JSON com vários nomes diferentes?

Igual:
[{nome: "joão"}, {nome: "pedro"}]

Alguém poderia me dar um exemplo?

---

Eu tentei fazer assim, mas porque ele retorna sempre o último item duas vezes? Tipo João na primeira e logo, Pedro duas vezes?

```
  $(".item-tbody .nome").each(function ()
   {
       obj.nome = $(this).parent().find('.nome').text();

        arrayObj.push(obj);

         nomeArray = JSON.stringify(arrayObj);
          alert(nomeArray);

   });
```

Comment: Será `JSON.stringify('[{nome: "joão"}, {nome: "pedro"}]');` ? https://jsfiddle.net/rwctqhu9/ . Não creio que haja uma maneira melhor com jquery, usa simplemente a função nativa de javascript

Comment: Sim. Ele vem de uma única variável. Tipo os dois vem da variável nome. Como que eu faço para quebrar os dois que fiquem igual no modelo acima?

Comment: Não é como está no link em cima que coloquei? Queres dois jsons, um para cada obj dentro do array, é isso?

Comment: Sim igual a este. Só que João e Pedro vem de uma única variável. Como que eu quebro para que fique igual ao que você disse acima?

Comment: Tenho a variável nome, que vem: João e Pedro.

Comment: Queres cada nome numa variável diferente? ex: `var name1 = 'joão'; var name2 = 'pedro';`

Comment: Tenho a variável nome, que vem: João e Pedro certo? Ela vem com estes dois nomes, mas eu quero que ela se quebre e coloque assim: [{nome: "joão"}, {nome: "pedro"}]

Comment: Assim https://jsfiddle.net/7vr9Lq3h/1/?

Comment: Cara eu fiz assim:    obj.nome = $(this).parent().find('.nome').text();
        arrayObj.push(obj);

          nomeArray = JSON.stringify(arrayObj);
          alert(nomeArray);

Comment: Ele aparece: [{"nome":"joão paulo"}]. Como que eu quebro eles?

Comment: Sim. Até deu certo, mas ainda ele corta os nomes: João, ele coloca: {"nome":"J"},{"nome":"o"} entende? 
          var people = $(this).parent().find('.nome').text();
          var names = [];
          for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {

           names.push({nome: people[i]});
          }
          alert(JSON.stringify(names));

Comment: Obrigado. Vou tentar procurar em outro fórum.

Answer (score 2):

O seu JSON não é válido ! Cole ele [nesse site](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) e valide-o, o seu JSON retorna:

> Expecting string or }, not [.

Eu criei um JSON válido de nomes para você. Lembrando que `{ } = objeto` e `[  ] = Array`.  Leia mais sobre JSON [aqui](http://www.json.org/).

`[{ "nome":"João"},{"nome":"Pedro"}]`

```js
obj =
[
   {
      "nome":"João"
   },
   {
      "nome":"Pedro"
   }
]

console.log(obj[0].nome)
console.log(obj[1].nome)
```